# Owl carousel click on slide to show description DIV uniquely

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

i'm using owl carousel, when i click on slide there is a description div open outside of owl carousel hierarchy.

Please help me out.

Thanks a lot

I'm trying click function but its toggle the all description div's at once

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-item").click(function() {
    $(".carousel-item-desc1,.carousel-item-desc2,.carousel-item-desc3,.carousel-item-desc4").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> need more here </div>
```

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Comment: Please update your question as a working example including any CSS and HTML

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Can These picture helpful ?

Comment: We really need to see code to reproduce this here - including a link to that carousel (perhaps a CDN in a snippet for that and the bootstrap;  I put a snippet in to get you started perhaps